# How can I provide constant power to an outlet downstream of a switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, garbage-disposal

I have a circuit that is controlling the garbage disposal, switch, and a downstream GFI. All in separate boxes. The supply looks like it is feeding through the disposal and moving to the switch and then to the GFI. The issue is that the GFI is switched, and it switches off (doesn’t trip) when I flip the switch for the garbage disposal on (which works). Any suggestions to isolate the GFI and get power to it without being on the switch?

Comment: 1 - 15A or 20A circuit? 2 - If you can (carefully, turn off the breaker first) remove all relevant junction box covers and take pictures showing all the wiring going in and out of each box, that would help. 3 - Make/Model and/or nameplate rating of the disposal would help as you may have a code issue if the disposal takes more than 50% of the circuit capacity.

Comment: Yeah, the outlet never should've been installed. It was probably someone's clever idea to add convenience. Remove the switch loop and power it from a different circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Run more cable.

**However**, consider also **why** it would be done this way - if the garbage disposal uses most of the capacity of the circuit, then the setup described allows use of (microwave/blender/toaster/etc.) without tripping the circuit, by switching it **off** when the disposal is **on.** Thus, it's probably a **3-way switch,** being used as "GFCI-on **or** Disposal-on but **not both** on." Which is a valid, if unusual, way to use one 3-way switch.

You might need to *run more cable* all the way to the service panel or sub-panel and a new breaker to have **both** things on all the time.

Comment: It’s definitely a three way switch that is being used. Do you think this would cause any safety issues to leave it and use it like it is?

Comment: Exactly what I thought about the 3-way switch.

Comment: Only if you have your hand in the disposal when you flip the switch, @Ben. Or if you have life-supporting equipment plugged into the outlet and turn the disposal on for too long.